# When is it necessary to compare treatment means in a two-way ANOVA model

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

This study is about how different treatments affect the quantity of some protein in the blood.

The explanatory variables are categorical (3 different treatments, T01, T02, T03; `trtgrp`); the dependent variables are the protein level (continuous, `logvncsf`). 30 subjects (`pidID`) are randomly assigned to three groups; the dependent variables were measured at multiple time points (`Timepoint`).

Visually this is expressed as follow. We want to know is there a difference between treatment groups.
[image]

I fit a 2-way ANOVA model with repeated measure (I dropped -7 for an experimental reason):

```
    csf_aov2 <- with(data3[data3$Timepoint != -7, ], 
             aov(logvncsf ~ Timepoint * trtgrp + Error(pigID)))
    summary(csf_aov2)
```

It turns out:

```
Error: pigID
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
Timepoint  1  1.577   1.577

Error: Within
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Timepoint          4  653.1  163.28  54.332 <2e-16 ***
trtgrp             2   21.5   10.76   3.581 0.0306 *  
Timepoint:trtgrp   8   23.7    2.96   0.985 0.4507    
Residuals        131  393.7    3.01                   
---
```

Since at the `trtgrp` level, there is a significant difference, I conducted pairwise comparisons at the factor level means over groups.

However, my partner wants to know *is there a difference between groups at each time points* eg, he wants to know is there a difference at time point 0 because they seem to be close.

Statistically, I understand what he wants as comparisons of cell means. I just wonder is it necessary given that we have already shown the factor level means are different collectively? In other words, does the difference at the group factor level equal to the differences between cell means at each time point? I keep having trouble differentiating these two concepts.

What my partner wants means pairwise comparisons at 0, 21, 30, 70, 100, respectively; will it pose any problems?

If that is legitimate, how to estimate the SD for each point under the repeated model?

Thank you for reading this long question!